# ORM for DELPHI win32

Tags: delphi, orm, bold-delphi

Does anyone know about an ORM or something similar for Delphi Win32.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Marco Cantu is a big believer in InstantObjects:

http://www.instantobjects.org/

Others include DObject:

http://www.macrobject.com/en/dobject/

and tiOPF

http://tiopf.sourceforge.net/Doc/overview/index.shtml

You also might be interested in the G Framework:

http://code.google.com/p/g-framework/

Answer (score 11):

Another Open Source ORM for Delphi 6-XE2, which is JSON based and Client/Server.

Can use its own in memory database layer or embedded SQLite3 database engine:
http://blog.synopse.info/category/Open-Source-Projects/SQLite3-Framework

*Edit:* A lot of improvements to this active framework, since this question was answered. It is able now to connect to any third-party database, and is changing its name: it is now called the [mORMot framework](http://blog.synopse.info/tag/mORMot).

Comment: The framework is now able to connect to any other database - see http://blog.synopse.info/category/Open-Source-Projects/mORMot-Framework

Answer (score 10):

There are a few, some of the more tried and tested are...

[Bold](http://dn.codegear.com/article/33058)

[TiOPF](http://tiopf.sourceforge.net/)

And [RemObjects](http://www.remobjects.com/da.aspx) also has a schema Mapping technology that is worth investigating

Comment: Bold is clearly the best ORM framework for Delphi Win32. But it is not available anymore from Codegear/Embarcadero. I don't understand how that company thinking about this!

Answer (score 9):

TMS Software is working on an ORM framework for Delphi: TMS Aurelius should be soon released :

[TMS Aurelius](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/blog.asp?post=208)

EDIT:
It's been already released, official site is http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/aurelius.asp

Comment: I am using it for an year now. It is bugs free, stable, support is awesome. It is helping me create a big application much more easily. I recommend.

Answer (score 6):

Another ORM for Delphi, which seems to be in active development, is [hcOPF](http://www.tpersistent.com/?page_id=44)

The project is open source licensed under LGPL/MPL and hosted on SourceForge at http://sourceforge.net/projects/larryhengensopf/.

---

**dorm, “[The Delphi ORM](http://code.google.com/p/delphi-orm/)”** by Daniele Teti, was officially published at ITDevCon, there is an introduction [here](https://docs.google.com/present/edit?id=0AXmQefqbQaVBZGRqNzRxdGRfN2dwNmZqOWR2). It works with PODOs which have no knowledge of the ORM.

Answer (score 5):

New in 2011: DORM - http://code.google.com/p/delphi-orm/. Some documentation can be found on [author's blog](http://www.danieleteti.it/category/programming/the-delphi-orm/).

Comment: In the Sample folders there are all the samples shown at ITDevCon2013 conferences. The samples starts from the very beginning and explain all the main features.

Answer (score 3):

Visit http://code.google.com/p/persiphi/ if your are addicted to Delphi 2010 or upper.

**Edit**:
*`Dead link`* as the owner likely has renounced to opensource it. Nevertheless, his master thesis work in portugese (pt-br) is still available [here](http://deschamps.blog.com/files/2011/03/Framework-ORM-Delphi-Monografia.pdf). A good source of inspiration for those in search of sample using latest bleeding edge features of Delphi (Annotation, Rtti...) in the realm of object persistence.

---

## UPDATE 1:

DevArt has released **[EntityDAC](http://www.devart.com/entitydac)** - An ORM for Delphi with LINQ support!

[image: EntityDAC]

It works even with D11 (Delphi 2007).

---

## UPDATE 2:

**[Marshmallow ORM framework](https://bitbucket.org/soundvibe/marshmallow/wiki/Home)** by Linas Naginionis.

It has joined join the outstanding **[Spring4D](https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d)** project as a *feature branch* as announced [here](http://www.soundvibe.net/blog/me-marshmallow-and-spring4d/).

To keep abreast of the latest news head to the Marshmallow **Google+** thriving [Community page](https://plus.google.com/communities/109564074300215925680).

Dubbed **MM** ORM Framework by its author, it's a promising one.

Comment: [guidok](http://www.delphipraxis.net/members/34544-guidok.html), member of the outstanding Delphi-PRAXIS forum, has also written a simple persistence framework. You can find it [here](http://www.delphipraxis.net/130160-einfaches-persistence-framework.html). You must register so as to download it.

Answer (score 2):

Jazz SDK, ORM is a part of the OPF part

http://jazz-sdk.googlecode.com

Comment: @Cesar Romero: Can you publish some entreprise application level sample project sample using jazz sdk ?

Answer (score 2):

Here you have one: http://code.google.com/p/delphiorm/

Answer (score 1):

I tried Remobject **[Data Abstract](http://www.dataabstract.com/da/)** for 1-2 year in some real world projects.

Some features are good (a very good binary comunication protocol), some other are simply pitfalls (it adds a something of chaotic code and you have to pass dialog by dialog every change you made on the schema).

It's good you define a schema of the model, it's bad you miss much of the power of SQL (es grouping by, a easy to use join, ecc).

I think that it's hard to fit a good ORM on top of the old VCL and TDataSet.

DatAbstact was a try but at the end I rewrited my application in another language because a good ORM and a good framework is a must have for a good application.

VCL is simply too old to fit well with modern concepts of application development.

Anyway i tried InstantObject and Bold, are two good ORM frameworks but not more supported.

Comment: I currently working to make Bold as opensource. It is ready for Delphi XE10 now. I think there is a decent chance for success.

Answer (score 0):

**Trysil** is a "lightweight" **ORM** for **Delphi** and supports:

- FirebirdSQL
- Microsoft SQL Server
- PostgreSQL
- SQLite.

https://github.com/davidlastrucci/Trysil