# Performance Improvement

Tags: delphi, orm

I am thinking about improving the performance of IO, I don't completely understand the IO structure and I would like some help from the developers here.

I think if all fields are read when the first command to get ID and class is executed and stored in Object store and then RetrieveObject gets objects from ObjectStore it might give some performance improvement. Does this make sense?

Regards

Sandeep

Comment: No. it doesn't! A little more info would be helpful (like what you are trying to do, which ORM tool are you using, a little code to demonstrate the problem)

Answer (score 1):

It would be a question to ask to http://www.instantobjects.org/#newsgroups or to IO authors directly.

You have some structure diagrams at http://www.instantobjects.org/diagrams.html

The included IOHelp.chm file has a lot of useful information.

IO has no official release since 2006. But the SVN version at sourceforge has support for Delphi 2010. I suggest you get this updated version first.

About performance Improvement, did you use the StartTransaction/CommitTransaction methods of your TInstantConnector instance? It could have a big performance improvement in writing.

About reading, I didn't find any caching mechanism of data in the source code (after a quick review - but I could have missed something). But there is a statement cache included, which is not enabled by default. See the Statement_Cache.txt file in the Docs

You could take a look at other ORM frameworks for Delphi, you've a list at [ORM for DELPHI win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422426/orm-for-delphi-win32)
I should of course recommend ours: http://synopse.info/forum/viewforum.php?id=2 which has caching of both statements and data implement. :)