# nhibernate and delphi

Tags: delphi, nhibernate

a Can you use nhibernate with delphi 
b if not do you know about any nhibernate

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Maybe english isn't your first language, but you'll get more help if you try to explain more clearly.  (b) above is particularly unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) NHibernate is specifically for the .NET platform, so if you want to use NHibernate with Delphi, you'll need to use something like [Delphi.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/delphinet/) or (as [Robert Love suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251876/nhibernate-and-delphi/5251960#5251960)) [Delphi Prism](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism).

b) Not sure what you're asking here.  Please try re-phrasing your question.

Answer (score 3):

[ORM for DELPHI win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/422426/orm-for-delphi-win32)

[Stackoverflow Delphi ORM search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdelphi%5D+orm)

Answer (score 2):

You can use nHibernate with [Delphi Prism](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism).   You can not use it with [Delphi Native](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi).

Answer (score 1):

[TMS Aurelius](http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/aurelius.asp) is very similar to NHibernate